# Как убрать голоса за закрытие

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1228778/%D0%9A%D0%B0c%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE-pypirc). В принципе, он был и так ясен. Но не посвящённым, видимо, не понятен. Я поправил его. Можно ли убрать голоса за закрытие?

Comment: можно закрыть, а потом переоткрыть

Comment: Не обращайте внимания. Они чего-то значат только если их 5 — и вопрос закрыт.

Comment: нужно как-то сообщить им https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MQHm.jpg

Comment: уважаемый @nörbörnën уберите пожалуйста Ваш голос

Comment: голос "Оставить открытым"

Comment: уважаемый @VictorVosMottor уберите пожалуйста Ваш голос и Вы

Comment: @hedgehogues Я убрал. ;)

Comment: если в течение какого-то времени не набираются голоса - они сбрасываются

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не обращайте внимания. Они чего-то значат только если их 5 — и вопрос закрыт. Так они не влияют на вопрос. Можно попросить в чате снять голоса, если хотите.

Comment: там и твой голос :)

Comment: @nörbörnën мой? Лол (=

Comment: @nörbörnën О, как ты увидел, точно, снял ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor сходил в очередь проверок https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MQHm.jpg, нашёл вопрос, поставил "оставить открытым", вернулся назад и сфоткал

Comment: @nörbörnën О... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Если хорошо поправили, то новые голоса за закрытие не будут добавляться. А если недостаточно хорошо .. придётся поправить получше и, если закроют, надеяться, что он наберет голоса на переоткрытие.

Ну и на будущее вам совет - ваш вопрос только для вас *"В принципе, он был и так ясен."*, а для остальных его все же надо детально описывать и формулировать. Как говорится, "телепаты в отпуске".